# How can I access Toolbar and change at Runtime on Xamarin Forms Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar

I have a Xamarin Forms project with two Toolbar files, one have a Image and the other is default without any change. What I need is use the one with Image only on HomePage of my project and use the other Toolbar in the other pages.

I am using MasterDetailPage.

I tried to access the toolbar direct on MainActivity, but once its loads I cant change the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Load the toolbar in the code separately for Home Page and for other pages.

Find the code below.

```
 var editToolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.edit_toolbar);
 editToolbar.Title = "Editing";
 editToolbar.InflateMenu (Resource.Menu.edit_menus);
 editToolbar.MenuItemClick += (sender, e) => {  
  Toast.MakeText(this, "Bottom toolbar tapped: " + e.Item.TitleFormatted,    ToastLength.Short).Show();
 };
```

Check this link
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/part-2-adding-a-second-toolbar/